# Not getting @OneToMany Annotation in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am not getting @OneTomany or @manytoone(relational kind of annotations) annotataions in spring boot ,so how do I get that ? Is there i required to change the POM file?

Comment: elaborate more. When and where u getting error?

Comment: You do have javax.persistence jar in your project build path.right?

Comment: I am creating maven project using spring and trying to create some entity classes i need to define the realtionship between some terms bt it is not showing the intellesence in eclipse...What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Add javax.persistence jar dependency in your POM file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After it, update(Maven update) your project.It should work.

Comment: Done . dependancy was missed by me. Thanx :)

Comment: you may select my answer as helpful :)

Comment: is thereany other dependancy specific to the spring ?? for relationship annotations??

Comment: I believe it should cover most of annotations.

Comment: yes . but iwas trying to get all the references from one roof , actually i m using spring boot. so thats why...so i got the solution. we can refer it from
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>